# C# COM Interop access violation calling Marshal.PtrToStructure

Tags: c#, com-interop

I’m trying to call an unmanaged method from C# that returns a pointer to a pointer to a struct .

The method seems to return a value but when I call Marshal.PtrToStructure using the pointer I get an access violation error.

The system is a Windows Server 2012 r2 and my code and the interop are compiled to 64bit.

Here are the signatures from the IDL:

```
typedef struct _tagCCatConfigInfo { 
        DWORD dwCCatConfigInfoFlags; 
        DWORD dwEnable; 
        DWORD dwCatFlags; 
        LPSTR pszRoutingType; 
        LPSTR pszBindDomain; 
        LPSTR pszUser; 
        LPSTR pszPassword; 
        LPSTR pszBindType; 
        LPSTR pszSchemaType; 
        LPSTR pszHost; 
        LPSTR pszNamingContext; 
        LPSTR pszDefaultDomain; 
        DWORD dwPort; 
        ISMTPServer *pISMTPServer; 
        ICategorizerDomainInfo *pIDomainInfo; 
        DWORD dwVirtualServerID; 
} CCATCONFIGINFO, *PCCATCONFIGINFO; 


interface ICategorizerParameters : IUnknown 
{ 
  HRESULT GetDSParameterA( 
          [in]  DWORD dwDSParameter, 
          [out] LPSTR *ppszValue); 

  HRESULT SetDSParameterA( 
          [in] DWORD dwDSParameter, 
          [in, unique] LPCSTR pszValue); 

  HRESULT RequestAttributeA( 
          [in, unique] LPCSTR pszName); 

  HRESULT GetAllAttributes( 
          [out] LPSTR **prgszAllAttributes); 

  HRESULT ReserveICatItemPropIds( 
          [in]  DWORD   dwNumPropIdsRequested, 
          [out] DWORD   *pdwBeginningPropId); 

  HRESULT ReserveICatListResolvePropIds( 
          [in]  DWORD   dwNumPropIdsRequested, 
          [out] DWORD   *pdwBeginningPropId); 

  HRESULT GetCCatConfigInfo( 
          [out] PCCATCONFIGINFO *ppCCatConfigInfo);od 
};
```

The managed counterparts:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)] 
  public struct _tagCCatConfigInfo 
  { 
    public uint dwCCatConfigInfoFlags; 
    public uint dwEnable; 
    public uint dwCatFlags; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]                 
    public string pszRoutingType; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public string pszBindDomain; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public string pszUser; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public string pszPassword; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public string pszBindType; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public string pszSchemaType; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public string pszHost; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public string pszNamingContext; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    public string pszDefaultDomain; 

    public uint dwPort; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] 
    public ISMTPServer pISMTPServer; 

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] 
    public ICategorizerDomainInfo pIDomainInfo; 

    public uint dwVirtualServerID; 
} 


[ComConversionLoss, Guid("86F9DA7B-EB6E-11D1-9DF3-00C04FA322BA"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)] 
[ComImport] 
public interface ICategorizerParameters 
{ 
  .... 
  .... 
  .... 

  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)] 
  void GetCCatConfigInfo([Out] ref IntPtr ppCCatConfigInfo); 
}
```

My managed calling code:

```
void IMailTransportCategorize.ExpandItem(ICategorizerParameters pICatParms, ICategorizerItem pICatItem, IMailTransportNotify pINotify, IntPtr pvNotifyContext) 
{ 
  IntPtr ppCCatConfigInfo = IntPtr.Zero; 

  try 
  { 
    pICatParms.GetCCatConfigInfo(out ppCCatConfigInfo); 

    _tagCCatConfigInfo theStruct = (_tagCCatConfigInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ppCCatConfigInfo, typeof(_tagCCatConfigInfo)); <-- Access violation 

  } 
  catch(exception ex) 
  } 
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message); 
  } 
  finally 
  { 
    if (null != pICatParms) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pICatParms); } 
    if (null != pICatItem) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pICatItem); } 
    if (null != pINotify) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pINotify); } 
  } 
}
```

This is where I get the access violation

```
tagCCatConfigInfo theStruct = (_tagCCatConfigInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ppCCatConfigInfo, typeof(_tagCCatConfigInfo))
```

The system crashes and the output window reads - A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
The error logs do not have any entries for the exception and the SMTP Service stops.

Any ideas?

Thanks 
Al

Comment: Just put the IntPtr value in the Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory1 window's Address box.  With the expectation that it is a junk pointer.  Slight mistakes in the interface declaration cause large problems, I can't see what you left out.

Comment: I did that and you are correct, none of the values I was expecting were there.